# Как собрать все функции в одну Python Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всем доброго времени суток, пишу бота на telebot, всё пашет исправного хотелось бы вопросы, записанные в функциях, поместить в одну функцию, пыталась что-то построить- не выходит. Помогите пожалуйста

'''

```
#УСТОЙЧИВЫЕ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ
#НА РУССКОМ
#ВОПРОС 1
def answ1(message):
    print(message.text)
    if message.text == "На русском":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отлично, напишите (Извините) на немецком ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ2)
    else:
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, ger)
#ВОПРОС 2
def answ2(message):
    first_answer = message.text
    print(first_answer)
    if first_answer == "Tut mir leit":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите (Я к сожалению пришёл не вовремя)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ3)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ2)
#ВОПРОС 3
def answ3(message):
    second_answer= message.text
    if second_answer == "Ich komme leider nicht punktlich":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите (Поэтому я приеду немного позже)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ4)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ3)
#ВОПРОС 4
def answ4(message):
    third_answer=message.text
    if third_answer == "Deswegen komme ich etwas spater":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите (Я пропустил автобус)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ5)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ4)
#ВОПРОС 5
def answ5(message):
    fourth_answer =message.text
    if fourth_answer == "Ich habe den Bus verpasst":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите (Но я буду в половине второго около Кинотеатра)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ6)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ5)
#ВОПРОС 6
def answ6(message):
    fifth_answer = message.text
    if fifth_answer == "Aber ich bin um halb zwei wor dem Kino":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите (Как насчёт того, что)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ7)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ6)
#ВОПРОС 7
def answ7(message):
    sixth_answer = message.text
    if sixth_answer == 'Wie ware es, denn':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите (Это для тебя подходит?)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ8)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ7)
#ВОПРОС 8
def answ8(message):
    seventh_answer = message.text
    if seventh_answer == 'Passt das fur dich?':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите (До скорого)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ9)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ8)
#ВОПРОС 9
def answ9(message):
    seventh_answer = message.text
    if seventh_answer == 'Bis gleich':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Немецкий")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Во сколько у меня урок?")
        markup.add(item1, item2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answ9)
```

'''

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы все вопросы и ответы держал как словарь, чтобы сверяться с поступающими ответами.

```
all_answers = {
    "Вводный вопрос": "На русском",
    "Отлично, напишите (Извините) на немецком": "Tut mir leit",
    "Напишите (Я к сожалению пришёл не вовремя)": "Ich komme leider nicht punktlich",
    "Напишите (Поэтому я приеду немного позже)": "Deswegen komme ich etwas spater",
    "Напишите (Я пропустил автобус)": "Ich habe den Bus verpasst",
    "Напишите (Но я буду в половине второго около Кинотеатра)": "Aber ich bin um halb zwei wor dem Kino",
    "Напишите (Как насчёт того, что)": "Wie ware es, denn",
    "Напишите (Это для тебя подходит?)": "Passt das fur dich",
    "Напишите (До скорого)": "Bis gleich"
}

def answers(message):
    answer = message.text
    if answer in all_answers:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        if answer != "Bis gleich"
            temp = list(all_answers)
            try:
                res = temp[temp.index(answer) + 1]
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                res = None
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(res))
        else:
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Немецкий")
            item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Во сколько у меня урок?")
            markup.add(item1, item2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неправильно! Попробуй ещё раз")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answers)
```

Таким образом мы проверяем поступивший ответ в списке правильных ответов. Если ответ правильный, то мы берем следующий ключ, который является вопросом и отправляем пользователю. Если ответ неверный то пользователь еще раз вводит ответ. Если ответ является последним, то мы шлем пользователю сообщение с двумя клавишами.